# Multiplying quantity and amount in different tables in same database

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

these are my tables

ORDER_ITEMS

```
+----------+--------+-----------------+------------+
| order_id |item_id |    item_name    |  quantity  |
+----------+--------+-----------------+------------+
|     1    |   1    |      coffee     |     2      |
|     2    |   2    |      shake      |     2      |
|     2    |   3    |    icecream     |     3      |
+----------+--------+-----------------+------------+
```

PRODUCT_INGREDIENT:

```
+--------+-----------------+--------+
|item_id | ingredient_id   | amount |
+--------+-----------------+--------+
|   1    |      123        |  10    |
|   1    |      124        |  15    |
|   2    |      125        |  10    |
|   2    |      124        |  15    |
|   2    |      123        |  10    |
|   2    |      126        |  15    |
|   3    |      124        |  15    |
|   3    |      123        |  10    |
|   3    |      126        |  15    |
+--------+-----------------+--------+
```

INVENTORY:

```
+--------+-----------------+--------+
|  id    | ingredient_id   | amount |
+--------+-----------------+--------+
|   1    |      123        |   80   |
|   2    |      124        |   70   |
|   3    |      125        |  100   |
|   4    |      126        |  100   |
+--------+-----------------+--------+
```

the sql I have is working but I need to multiply the (amount)column in PRODUCT_INGREDIENT table to the column(quantity) in ORDER_ITEMS table
before

this is the sql statement

```
UPDATE inventory i 
INNER  JOIN (
  SELECT p.ingredient_id, sum(p.amount) amount
    FROM product_ingredient p 
   INNER JOIN  order_items o on o.item_id = p.item_id
   WHERE o.order_id = 1
   GROUP BY p.ingredient_id
) p ON  i.ingredient_id = p.ingredient_id 
SET i.amount = i.amount - p.amount
```

I want my inventory to look like this after query
INVENTORY:

```
+--------+-----------------+--------+
|  id    | ingredient_id   | amount |
+--------+-----------------+--------+
|   1    |      123        |  100   |
|   2    |      124        |  100   |
|   3    |      125        |  100   |
|   4    |      126        |  100   |
+--------+-----------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking to your data sample seems you need add  the result of the subquery

```
UPDATE inventory i 
INNER  JOIN (
  select p.ingredient_id, sum(p.amount*o.quantity) amount
  from product_ingredient p 
  INNER JOIN  order_items o on o.item_id = p.item_id
  WHERE o.order_id = 1
  GROUP BY p.ingredient_id
) p ON  i.ingredient_id = p.ingredient_id 
SET i.amount = i.amount + p.amount
```

Comment: it shows an error "Unknown column 'o.quantity' in 'field list'"

Comment: in your table schema/data sample  you have a column  named  quantity in table order_items  .. are you sure the  name is really quantity and not qty or somethings other???  ..eventually show us the real table schema for order_items table

Comment: i misspelled quantity in my database, i corrected it and now it looks like this
INVENTORY, 123 = 120,124=130 INSTEAD OF 123=80, 124=70

Comment: i just changed addition to subtraction

````
UPDATE inventory i 
INNER  JOIN (
  select p.ingredient_id, sum(p.amount*o.quantity) amount
  from product_ingredient p 
  INNER JOIN  order_items o on o.item_id = p.item_id
  WHERE o.order_id = 1
  GROUP BY p.ingredient_id
) p ON  i.ingredient_id = p.ingredient_id 
SET i.amount = i.amount - p.amount 
````

Comment: @Remaster   . you can mark as acepted  one only answer  but (do the fact you have more than 15 retputation)  you can also mark  the answer  all you like as useful (clicking on upper arrow left to each answer ...  so you could also ad  an upvote to others  answer  (and mine too if you like)

Answer (score 1):

You can use such an UPDATE statement :

```
UPDATE inventory i 
 INNER JOIN (
  SELECT p.ingredient_id, sum(p.amount*o.quantity) amount
  FROM product_ingredient p 
  INNER JOIN  order_items o on o.item_id = p.item_id
  WHERE o.order_id = 1
  GROUP BY p.ingredient_id
) p ON  i.ingredient_id = p.ingredient_id 
SET i.amount = i.amount + p.amount
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=14c5e26ae07cd24511ebdb074a36ae05)</kbd>

Only `ingredient_id` 123 and 124 are matched for the whole query. So, only  they're updated.

Comment: it shows an error "Unknown column 'o.quantity' in 'field list'"

Comment: but you have a column `quantity` within the table `order_items`, don't you? @Remaster Btw, please have a look at the Demo already been shared before.

Comment: yes, sorry I misspelled it on my database. I already fixed it and it works perfectly except that you added (SET i.amount = i.amount + p.amount ) instead of subtracted. Great work, thank you but I already marked another answer as right, I upvoted you tho